# Java - Searching for Properties Keys in source code

Tags: java, properties, internationalization

I have to write a Java programm that searches for properties keys in a project and writes them without a value to a properties file. Those keys do always look like this:
 `new I18nString("key")` or `m_I18n.msg("key")` or `LOG.warning("key")`

What would be the easiest way to go through all the packages and classes to pick those keys?

Comment: What kind of "project"? What technology/technologies? The proper way of parsing source code would probably involve Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). Can you elaborate more on what's your goal?

Comment: @Iob: I have accomplished exactly same(with much more functionalty) what you want with this approach: I wrote a java program to take .properties and extract all keys, these keys I am fetching in shellscript and grepping each one on the source code. The grep result I am processing to get a report about which all file those keys are using. This is just an very high level description.

But my implementaiton creates lots of noises if ResourceBundle have very short and lower case keys like PUT, DELETE, Link, Text because such Keys occure many times in sourcecode.